# How can I treat a short integer as an array of elements in C?

Tags: c, arrays, byte

So I have an integer stored as a short. Let's say:

```
short i = 3000;
```

Which in binary is:

```
0011 0000 0000 0000
```

I was told I can treat it as an array of two elements where each element is a byte basically, so:

```
i[0] = 0011 0000
i[1] = 0000 0000
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Who told you this and in what context?  There's a short answer, but without knowing the context it might just confuse you even more.

Comment: Look up *typecasting*.

Comment: Supposing that "short" is 4 bytes long is not good. It depends on architecture/OS.

Comment: isn't 3000 in binary 0000101110111000?

Comment: Sorry, forgive. Yes, short should be at least 2 bytes.

Comment: Sorry, 3000 is the hex value of the binary I have in the question, not the decimal, but that is the binary I'm trying to manipulate.

Comment: @JohnCena:Well, I hope you get the idea anyway.

Comment: `3000` isn't a hex value.  Did you mean `0x3000` ?  You can edit your question, check the edit link right under it.

Comment: You could define a `union` that contains a short int and a char array of 2 bytes.  Then access the data using the appropriate entry in the union.  Do note that the actual contents of the two bytes will differ (be swapped) depending if the underlying architecture is `little endian` or `big endian`.   Note this assumes that a `short int` is 16 bits, which might not be true especially on a 64 bit CPU

Answer (score 4):

You could do it like this (assuming `short` is 2 bytes)

```
short i = 3000; // 3000 in Binary is: 00001011 10111000
unsigned char x[2] = {0};
memcpy(x, &i, 2);
```

Now `x[0]` will be 10111000 and `x[1]` 00001011 if this code runs on little endian machine. And reverse will hold true in case of big endian machine.

Btw. Your binary representation of 3000 looks wrong

Comment: `unsigned char[sizeof(short)]` to remove the assumption.

Comment: @zwol:in that case I also have to change memcpy parameter, I will leave like this, hoping OP will at least get idea.